# Uploading Files using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, multipart

I used the AngularJS example provided in http://jsfiddle.net/JeJenny/ZG9re/ to upload a file from the local machine.

It gives no errors and the google chrome console response is shown as follows,

```
file is {"webkitRelativePath":"","lastModifiedDate":"2008-09-25T10:47:10.000Z","name":"MOVIES.txt","type":"text/plain","size":266} 

XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost:8087/alsystem/profilePics". 
successful
```

But when the profilePics folder is checked, the file I uploaded is not available.

What might be the reason for the file to be not available, though the code returns successful.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your rights on your WebServer?

Had the problem on my PHP-Script aswell, after I set the full rights (on test environment) with: chmod -R 777 on the folder to store, it worked.

Comment: No, the it has the write permissions.

Comment: Can you show your server side code where you handle the upload?